# How to pass form data on submit listener so that axios can post form data?

Tags: javascript, ajax, axios

I have a form like the following.

```
<form class="comment-post" method="POST" action="/api/v1/comment/<%= post._id %>" enctype="multipart/form-data>
   <div class="comment-section">
         <textarea rows="4" name="comment"></textarea>
         <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

There can be more than one form with class 'comment -post'. I would like to add event listener on form submit so that the request is ajax like, as in the following.

```
const commentPostForms = document.querySelectorAll('.comment-post')

commentPostForms.forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()

        axios
            .post(this.action)
            .then(res=>{
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch(console.error);

    })
})
```

My question is how do I submit the form data along with my axios request. Currently, no form data is being sent.

I tried the following (edited),

```
function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const formData = new FormData(e.target)

     axios
        .post(e.target.action, formData)
         .then(res=>{
              console.log(res)
          })
         .catch(console.error);

 })
```

On the node js express server side I am doing console of the received object to see if the data has been actually passed.

```
router.post('/comment/:post_id/', comment );

const comment = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.json(req.body);
}
```

I do not see 'comment' on req.body console.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to generate the form data using the target of the event. So you should do:

```
const commentPostForms = document.querySelectorAll('.comment-post')

commentPostForms.forEach(form => {
    form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const formData = new FormData(e.target);

        axios
            .post(e.target.action, formData)
            .then(res=>{
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch(console.error);

    })
})
```

Also, in your html set the enctype to form data. So you will have:

```
<form class="comment-post" enctype="multipart/formdata" action="/api/v1/comment/<%= post._id %>">
   <div class="comment-section">
       <textarea rows="4" name="comment"></textarea>
       <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

If you want to check if they key/pair your form data is really there. You can do after generating the form data:

```
for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
   console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

Comment: I do need action as i am posting data to an api

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've just corrected it, so you can get the action from the event as well. So you get the url dynamically

Comment: Evething seems alright, but i am not able to see the 'comment' data on console.log in the serverside.

Comment: If you need to handle the form data in node js. You can use multer: https://github.com/expressjs/multer. Also, instead of using form data you could just send your request as json. Such: `form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        axios
            .post(e.target.action, {
              name: e.target.elements[0].name
            })
            .then(res=>{
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch(console.error);

    })`